# Powershell RegEx: get content from and until specific char

Tags: regex, powershell

I tried my best, but RegEx is still a torture to me.

Let's assume I have the following String:

> a=this is an application o=this is an object grp=this is a group

I'm in need of a regEx which saves the content after "a=", "o=" and "grp=" into variables:

> $a = "this is an application"
>  $o = "this is an object" 
>  $grp = "this is a group"

How can this be done?
 Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Showing us your best would be a good start. I see `<br>` in your code blocks. Does your string contain new lines? Honestly though I would skip regex for this one and just look at `ConvertFrom-StringData` or `ConverFrom-String` which would do all the work here for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This do the work and has been tested.

```
$s = "a=this is an application o=this is an object grp=this is a group"
if($s -match 'a=(?<a>[^=]*)=(?<o>[^=]*)=(?<grp>[^=]*)')
{
    Write-Host "$"
    $a = $Matches.a.substring(0,$Matches.a.length-2)
    $o = $Matches.o.substring(0,$Matches.a.length-4)
    $grp = $Matches.grp
}
Write-Host ">> a: [$a]" 
Write-Host ">> o: [$o]"
Write-Host ">> grp: [$grp]"
```

The tips is to use (?) to identify captured string by name and to use [^=]* to stop search when character is equal to =.

The 2 first string contains the name of the following variable, so I use SUBSTRING() function to remove it.

Naturally, there are a problem when string value contains a equality character :-)
If this situation exists, I think that REGEX is not a good solution.

The split solution is a better solution

```
$s = "a=this is an application o=this is an object grp=this is a group"
$x,$a,$o,$grp = $s -split("a=| o=| grp=")
Write-Host ">> a: [$a]" 
Write-Host ">> o: [$o]"
Write-Host ">> grp: [$grp]"
```

and in this situation more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(?:.=([a-zA-Z\s]*[^\w=]))|(?:.+=([a-zA-Z\s]*))`

Answer (score 0):

This will create variables for each value.

`$Split` has the following value:

```
a=
this is an application 
o=
this is an object 
grp=
this is a group
```

A simple Do/while loop with  a replace method to remove the `=` allows us to create the variables:

```
$String = 'a=this is an application o=this is an object grp=this is a group'
$Split = $String -split "(\w{1,3}[=])"
$Count = $Split.Count
$c = 1

do
{
    New-Variable -Name ($Split[$c].replace("=","").Trim()) -Value ($Split[$c + 1].Trim()) -Force
    $c = $c + 2
}

Until ($c -eq $count)
```